# Which is faster/better to store collection of strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, isset

I am trying to create an array to store which nodes I have visited before. The nodes will be uniquely represented by a string, and the ***string can be very long***. Hence, I am wondering which of the two implementations will be faster or more scalable.

```
$stateString = "..... ....";
$states = array();
```

1) Storing the stateString as a key

```
$states[$stateString] = true; // I just want to set the key in the array
$visited = isset($states[$stateString]);
```

2) Storing the stateString as a value

```
$states[] = $stateString;
$visited = in_array($stateString, $states);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing as a key is much faster (for the random look-ups you are talking about).